# Finding max integer value in NSArray consisting of NSDictionary objects

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, max

Is there any quick and efficient way of finding max `int` value in `NSArray` that consists of `NSDictionary` objects? I mean sure, I can implement `for` cycle going through, but I am looking for some API function that's already tweaked to maximum speed since it's operating with fairly large amount of data.

`[(int, string, string), (int, string, string), (int, string, string)]`

I tried working with `valueForKeyPath` but that really didn't help me so far, since it works with "ordinary" NSArray objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of curiosity, I did a little comparison of `valueForKeyPath:` vs simple iteration. On my iMac core i7 running OS X 10.8.2, the simple iteration is about twice as fast for an array of 10M elements.

Here's the test program I made:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#undef NDEBUG
#import <assert.h>
#import <limits.h>
#import <stdio.h>
#import <stdlib.h>

#define ELEMENTS_IN_ARRAY 10000000

NSArray *newArrayWithDictionaryElementCount(int count) {
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        [arr addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"value%d", i], @"string",
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:rand()], @"int",
                        nil]];
    }
    return arr;
}

int maxIntValueByKeyPathInArray(NSArray *arr) {
    return [(NSNumber *)[arr valueForKeyPath:@"@max.int"] intValue];
}

int maxIntValueByIterationInArray(NSArray *arr) {
    int max = INT_MIN;
    for (NSDictionary *dict in arr) {
        int val = [(NSNumber *)[dict valueForKey:@"int"] intValue];
        if (val > max) {
            max = val;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

NSTimeInterval timeExecutionOf(void(^blockToTime)(void)) {
    NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
    blockToTime();
    return -[start timeIntervalSinceNow];
}

int main (int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSArray *arr = newArrayWithDictionaryElementCount(ELEMENTS_IN_ARRAY);
        assert(maxIntValueByIterationInArray(arr) == maxIntValueByKeyPathInArray(arr));
        (void) printf("Time by key path: %f s\n", timeExecutionOf(^{ maxIntValueByKeyPathInArray(arr); }));
        (void) printf("Time by iteration: %f s\n", timeExecutionOf(^{ maxIntValueByIterationInArray(arr); }));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The results on my machine:

```
$ clang -fobjc-arc -framework Foundation -O4 -march=corei7 -o arraytest arraytest.m
$ ./arraytest
Time by key path: 1.809646 s
Time by iteration: 0.886023 s
```

My hypothesis is that the iterative solution is already about as fast as can be for these data structures; there is no getting around having to do the dictionary look-up for each array element. Furthermore, this custom-made iterative solution benefits from knowing that all the `NSNumber` objects have `int` values; using `isGreaterThan:` for comparison slows things down somewhat (but it's still faster than `valueForKeyPath:`). Any general-purpose library method would almost certainly incur that penalty internally…

Comment: The main reason for the difference seems to be that comparing `NSNumber` objects is much slower than comparing `int`. - I have modified `maxIntValueByIterationInArray` in your program to work with `NSNumber` objects with the effect that then both function have almost the same execution time.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I tried that version myself and came to the same conclusion (although on my computer there was still about 30% advantage to iteration). Anyhow, I edited the answer to mention this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know now fast this is, but you can use the built-in `@max` operator with `valueForKeyPath:`:

```
NSArray *array = @[
    @{ @"value" : @5, @"name" : @"foo"},
    @{ @"value" : @7, @"name" : @"bar"},
    @{ @"value" : @3, @"name" : @"abc"}
];

NSNumber *maximum = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@max.value"];
NSLog(@"%@", maximum);
// Output: 7
```

In this example, `value` is the dictionary key, and the value is a `NSNumber` object, because you cannot store an `int` in a dictionary.

(See [Collection Operators](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-SW10) in the "Key-Value Coding Programming Guide".)

**UPDATE:** This is definitely not the fastest solution, as Arkku has shown in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, There is a better way to sort an array consists of the `NSDictionary`. In the given snatch of code it consists the dictionary of places. Each dictionary object consists of Name and Distance keys.

The array would be look like:

```
(   
     {      name = "Electronics Store";
           distance = 9;
     },{      name = "Caffeteria Store";
          distance = 29;
    }    
)
```

Here the sorting is done on the basis of "key distance" of dictionary. Please make sure the key distance need to be an int value.

For example :

```
[detail_dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[distance intValue]] forKey:@"distance"];
```

NOTE: It makes the distance as a int value for sorting.

After that just do the sorting the default method of `NSMutableArray`:
CODE:

```
 [arr_details sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES]]]
```